# MVC4 Parse json returned from Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, stringbuilder

I am using a stored procedure to query an internal database based on some user input.

I've got it to the point where my ajax request will receive a JSON string which my controller builds with StringBuilder. The response string is formatted exactly like the following:

```
{ "Head":[ { "FIRST_NAME":"JOHN","LAST_NAME":"SMITH","STORE":"1","COMPANY":"1"} ]}
```

I want to insert these values into some html input tags via jQuery but I am having a hard time finding a way to parse these correctly.

```
         $('#number').blur(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Home/SearchUser",
            type: "get",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { reqMem: $("#number").val() },
            success: function (response) {

                    // This is where I need to parse and shove some values
                    $("#name").val(response.name)
                    $("#store").val(response.name)
                    // etc.. 
            },

            error: function (textStatus) {
                alert("error: " + textStatus);
            },
        });
    });
```

The following is my **controller** method. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to this.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public string SearchUser(string reqMem)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("I manually have my string here")
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spx_findReqMember", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reqMemName", reqMem);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);

        StringBuilder JsonString = new StringBuilder();

        //Exception Handling
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            JsonString.Append("{ ");
            JsonString.Append("\"Head\":[ ");

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                JsonString.Append("{ ");
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j < dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                     JsonString.Append("\"" + dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() +
                     "\":" + "\"" +
                     dt.Rows[i][j].ToString().TrimEnd() + "\",");
                    }
                    else if (j == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                     JsonString.Append("\"" +
                     dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" +
                     "\"" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString().TrimEnd() + "\"");
                    }
                }

                /*end Of String*/
                if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                { JsonString.Append("} "); }
                else
               { JsonString.Append("}, "); } }

            JsonString.Append("]}");
            return JsonString.ToString(); }
        else
        { return reqMem;  } }
```

Comment: As a general hint, I would strongly recommend reading up on the JavaScript serialiser class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx. This would allow you to store your data into an object, then automatically serialise it for you, handling all the escaping itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at parseJSON, sounds like that might help you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

I also recommend you to see this post:
[How to make simple JSON object using C# string Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533374/how-to-make-simple-json-object-using-c-sharp-string-builder)

Comment: I checked it out and making a small model class to let the framework help me is going to work (Specifically Darin's answer 'Never do that') Thanks again.